# What does "two patterns Shallow" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *[Greyhound (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_(film))*, Commander Ernie says to Mister Lopez about firing U-Boat:

> Commander Ernie: Mister Lopez, prepare to engage that target. When he
> dives, we're gonna hammer him with **two patterns Shallow**, then deep.

What does "two patterns Shallow" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commander of the ship was ordering [depth charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_charge) to be deployed. Depth charges are not precision weapons one can aim at a target. Instead, they are launched in an area where a target is suspected. So, launching multiple in a spread pattern greatly increases the chances of a hit.

The detonation fuses on a depth charge work by measuring e static pressure of the water around it. The lower it goes in depth, the higher the pressure around it. The fuses are adjustable on the surface to detonate at a depth preselected before their deployment.